# What's the best way to build a very flexible/dynamic "header" in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I need to build a `UICollectionView` with a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and a **very dynamic "header"** (for clarity, I'll call it "view A" to avoid mixing it with a true collection view header) but I'm not sure about what can be the best way to do that: **collectionViewCell**, **header** or **supplementary view**?

What I mean by flexible, the bullet point being ordered by decreasing importance:

1. View A will contain buttons and subviews that need to detect gestures so I must be able to detect actions on subviews of view A.
2. I need to be able to reload data on the collection view without reloading view A.
3. I need to be able to update the layout of subviews of view A whenever I want (on `viewDidScroll` of the collection view `delegate` for example, update according to `contentOffset` changes).
4. If possible, I'd like to be able to change the frame of view A dynamically (I mean without having to invalidate the layout). I would like view A to be sticky at the top and shrink while scrolling until it disappear. Have a look at recently launched "Secret" app to see what I mean (done on `UITableView` for them). Though I could just scroll without changing the frame and cheat by changing the layout of subviews (see point 3) in order to give the sensation of a sticky header.

What do you think is the best component to do that? Can I use a `UICollectionViewCell`, a header or a supplementary view? If so which one? If not, do you think of an alternative way I could use to have the same behavior (transparent header and view A behind the collection view? adding view A somewhere else, where, in the view hierarchy?).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the UICollectionReusableView class.

You can register your nib on the CollectionView as "SupplementaryView" (registerNib:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:, use the UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader kind of view)

then you have to implement the collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath: method in your delegate and make sure to return something for the UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader kind.

and finally you have to implement the collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection: method of your UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout to set the size of your header.

Let me know if it help.

Comment: Thanks thibaut. I'm pretty sure changing the frame (bullet point 4) dynamically on scroll is not possible but I could "cheat" and make the subviews go down to give the feel of a sticky shrinking header.

Comment: What worries me the most though is bullet point 2: I don't see how I could reload the data section without reloading the header supplementary view. I can reload a section independantly of the others so I could insert another section just for my header and in this new section, I'm now wondering what is the most flexible between all of the stated components

Comment: maybe with reloadItemsAtIndexPaths with the header indexPath?